# Mock function inside function

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to mock a function that makes an API call using mocker patch. However, it doesn't work, not even in this simple example. The class_abcd.process_weather()
uses the actual get_weather() as opposed to the mocked one.

The directory structure is the following:

```
-source
  -sub
    -using_output.py
  -weather_api.py
```

using_output.py

```
from source.weather_api import get_weather

class abcd():
    def process_weather(self):
        weather = get_weather()
        return "processed " + weather
```

weather_api.py

```
def get_weather():
    return "weather"
```

I'm trying to test the process_weather and faking the get_weather from the weather api.

```
from pytest_mock import mocker
def test_weather_in_batch(mocker):
    # Setup
    fake_weather = "fake_weather"
    # Actual
    class_abcd = abcd()
    mocker.patch('weather_api.get_weather', return_value=fake_weather)
    actual = class_abcd.process_weather()

    # Expected
    expected = "processed " + "fake_weather"
    # Asset
    assert expected == actual
```

Comment: This article explains why your mocking is not working https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201908/why_your_mock_doesnt_work.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using mock, you need to specify what import you want to patch, not the underlying module/function.

```
from pytest_mock import mocker
def test_weather_in_batch(mocker):
    # Setup
    fake_weather = "fake_weather"
    # Actual
    class_abcd = abcd()
    mocker.patch('source.sub.using_output.get_weather', return_value=fake_weather)
    actual = class_abcd.process_weather()

    # Expected
    expected = "processed " + "fake_weather"
    # Asset
    assert expected == actual
```

In your case you are importing `get_weather` into `using_output.py`.

Because you want the use the mocked version of `get_weather` in `using_output.py`, this is what you need to patch.